# Strip all formatting from pasted text except bold, italics, underline

Tags: c#, winforms, rtf

I have a project where the user needs to be able to paste text in to a RichTextBox, but the pasted text must retain *only* bolded, italicized, and underlined formatting.

Currently, I have the following:

```
        DataFormats.Format format = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Text);
        rtbMain.Paste(format);
```

...which strips all formatting and just pastes the text from the clipboard.

What actually needs to be removed is the first line of the following, as well as the closing bracket (which I'm not quite sure of how to do).

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033\deflangfe1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fmodern\fprq1\fcharset0 Courier New;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\nowidctlpar\fi720\sl480\slmult1\f0\fs24\par
}
```

Comment: Try googling for "rtf parser .net"